# Is iterating LASSO a reasonable idea?

Tags: feature-selection, lasso

Can Lasso regression be performed multiple times to systematically clean/remove parameters from a model? Would there be downsides to doing so/would it be considered poor practice?

Comment: Please explain what "performed multiple times" might mean.  Is there any reason to suppose it would yield different results the second time around?

Comment: [Least angle regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least-angle_regression) usually produces the same result as lasso regression, and may be more intuitive in terms of the inclusion/exclusion of particular numbers of variables.

Comment: If you want a certain number of predictors, just increase your penalty coefficient until you get said number of non-zero coefficients.

Comment: Do you mean running a LASSO regression, removing the variables whose parameters and shrunk to zero, and then running another LASSO regression on the remaining variables?

Comment: If you are thinking of something like 1) running Lasso, 2) eliminating the smallest coefficient from the model, 3) repeating steps 1) & 2) until some criterion is met (e.g. minimum error on validation set), then what you are describing sounds like the "backward elimination" flavor of [Stepwise regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stepwise_regression) (sometimes called "stepwise selection").

Answer (score 1):

You can try that. Doing so naively (i.e. setting hyperparameters only for each sequential fit, or using cross-validation for each sequential fit) seems likely to lead to increase the risk of overfitting. The way one could do this more appropriately is to do a cross-validation loop around the whole process, i.e. the number of sequential fitting steps, as well as the penalty parameters in each fitting step then become hyperparameters of an overall method that you'd want to tune overall rather than for each step in isolation.

A simple related idea is the relaxed LASSO, where you first do LASSO, but then combine the LASSO fit with a unconstrained fit of the model with the LASSO-selected terms. That's kind of a two-step version of what you describe, if the non-regularized fit gets all the weight (of course that's also only equivalent, if one decided for no regularization in the second LASSO fit of your approach).

Comment: At face value this approach is very likely to result in a poor calibration curve.  It seems to be aimed at preserving predictive discrimination but doesn't seem to pay attention to absolute accuracy.

Comment: I had to puzzle whether it actually matters to perform lasso in a sequential way but your final paragraph explains it well. However, it seems more difficult...

Comment: ...When you sequentially perform lasso and remove parameters each time (I believe that this is what the OP intended to do), then you are gonna end up with the same model. The optimal solution is the same with or without the elimination of variables that do not turn up in the solution. At least, that is what it may seem like...

Comment: ... But without the additional variables it might be that the tuning of hyper-parameters ends up differently in the training and validation steps (so the key point is in the change of these hyper parameters as the result of the removed variables). The removed variables could have been what keeps the other variables from creating a better fit (with less bias)....

Comment: What you described as "relaxed lasso" (lasso followed by unconstrained fit) was proposed by Efron et al. under the name "Lars-OLS hybrid", and is only a special case of the relaxed lasso. In general, the relaxed lasso (Meinshausen 2006) uses a first lasso to identify the relevant variables, followed by a second lasso to estimate the coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

I remember doing something like this to observe how the estimated shrinkage factors  $$ \left | \beta_{j}^{lasso} \right |/\left | \beta_{j}^{ols} \right |$$ evolves over iterations. I quickly tried to do another experiment for your question. As far as I understand, you want to run lasso regressions several times and discard the predictors for each iteration whenever they are assigned zero coefficients. If that was the question, here is an example for Boston data set with 101 iterations (First set of coefficients are estimated using ols, other 100 are 'lasso iterations')

```
library(ggplot2); library(zoo); library(MASS); 
library(glmnet); data(Boston)

dim(Boston) # 13 predictors
[1] 506  14 

# linear model
lm.boston <- lm(formula = medv~., data = Boston)

# defining the parameter list
params <- list()

# initialize lasso (first iteration)
optim.lambda <- cv.glmnet(x = as.matrix(Boston[, -14]), y = as.vector(Boston[, 14]))$lambda.1se

lasso.boston<- glmnet(x = as.matrix(Boston[, -14]), y = as.vector(Boston[, 14]), 
                  lambda = optim.lambda)

params[[1]] <- coef(lasso.boston)[-1,]

# start iterating over 2:100
for(i in seq(99) + 1) {
    coefs <- coef(lasso.boston)[-1,]
    pred.list <- names(coefs)[coefs != 0] # remove coefficients that are shrunk to 0

    optim.lambda <- cv.glmnet(x = as.matrix(Boston[, pred.list]), y = as.vector(Boston[,"medv"]))$lambda.1se

    lasso.boston<- glmnet(x = as.matrix(Boston[, pred.list]), y = as.vector(Boston[,"medv"]),
                  lambda = optim.lambda)

    params[[i]] <- coef(lasso.boston)[-1,] # collect estimated coefficients 
}

params <- c(list(coef(lm.boston)[-1]), params) # binding ols and lasso     estimations

# rbind'ing all coefficients
foo <- function (...)
# thanks to   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21605401/why-does-rbindlist-not-respect-column-names
{
  dargs <- list(...)
  if (!all(vapply(dargs, is.vector, TRUE))) 
    stop("all inputs must be vectors")
  if (!all(vapply(dargs, function(x) !is.null(names(x)), TRUE))) 
    stop("all input vectors must be named.")
  all.names <- unique(names(unlist(dargs)))
  out <- do.call(rbind, lapply(dargs, `[`, all.names))
  colnames(out) <- all.names
  out
}

coef.path <- do.call(foo, params); coef.path[which(is.na(coef.path), arr.ind = T)] <- 0
autoplot(zoo(coef.path), facet = NULL) + geom_point()
```

Here are the parameter estimations over 101 models. As mentioned, first set of coefficients are obtained via ols and rest is via iterated lasso.
[image]

Model size over iterations

```
unlist(lapply(params, length)) # to see how many non-zero parameters are left in the model 

[1] 13 13  8  7  7  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3
[33]  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3
[65]  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3
[97]  3  3  3  3  3
```

If the plot is not sufficient, you can check what values the parameters take in each step using the *params* list.

I am still new to this kind of illustrations, so excuse my terrible formatting :-)

Hope that helps.

@whuber
I wanted to add an example so the post owner could try it with his/ her own data. What I see from my own example is that iterating the lasso is actually not a good idea.

Considering the Least angle regression algorithm for Lasso solution from Prof. Tibshirani's page:

1. Start with all coefficients bj equal to zero.
2. Find the predictor xj most correlated with y
3. Increase the coefficient bj in the direction of the sign of its correlation with y. Take residuals r=y-yhat along
   the way. Stop when some other predictor xk has as much correlation
   with r as xj has.
4. Increase (bj, bk) in their joint least squares
   direction, until some other predictor xm has as much correlation
   with the residual r.
5. Continue until: all predictors are in the model

Lasso is already an iterative algorithm that stops when each coefficient are penalized enough (and we already decide when to stop using cross-validation when frequentist approach is preferred). What I have done above is just to re-estimate by discarding variables at each step, which actually seems more like a  stepwise regression algorithm.

Comment: Could you tell us what you think your example shows?

Comment: @yahsin Can you think of situations/datasets where this iterative procedure would yield more useful result?

Answer (score 0):

It might create an underfit model, because the first model already has the optimal value of lambda through cross-validation.  Each subsequent round has a certain probability of rejecting a worthwhile predictor due to random roll of the cross validation folds, and because you've imposed an artificial variable selection (once a variable is gone, it's gone...) there's no way for the variable to get selected again.

You might consider bootstrapping instead.  Constructing lasso models for 100 bootstrapped samples of your data set should produce interesting statistics for the distribution of each coefficient and the fraction of samples where the variable was selected, akin to a p-value.  I don't know if there is a formal statistical validity for bootstrapping lasso, but even in absence of this, it should have practical value.